# Unable to reconnect jenkins slave automatically after restart

Tags: windows, jenkins, debian, master-slave

I have a Jenkins master (Linux Debian) and 4 slaves (Windows 7) which are connected via JNLP. 
The jenkins slave service works well in each slave. However when I restart a slave machine, the connection breaks down for all the slaves and the reconnection is established again only if the Jenkins master is restarted.

What should I do?

Comment: It's not possible by default, I'm looking for a plugin which may enable this.

Comment: @Slomojo any success?

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment, there isn't one that does this

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue with the following command:

```
sc triggerinfo <service_name_of_jenkins_slave> start/networkon stop/networkoff
```

Answer (score -2):

You may need to install the slave as a windows service.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

update:

### Installation as a task

If for some reason the service crashes a lot, you may want to [install a task to start jenkins slave through the task scheduler](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler).

1. right click on computer (either on desktop icon or menu option)

   [image: right click and manage]
2. find the task scheduler

   [image: find the task scheduler]
3. create a basic task

   [image: create a basic task]

follow the other steps from [this wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler).

Comment: I already installed the slave as a windows service. But the issue still exists :(

Comment: The installation as a task does not solve the problem. Is there another solution?